# Asp.Net Control Value return undefined in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my project i need change visible of dynamic asp control when click label based on textbox values. So i first tried to get textbox value when click label but its return `undefined`. I am search and get two methods i tried that also it return same.

My Try :

```
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

                  $(document).ready(function() {

                      $(document).on("click", "#lblShow", function() {

                      alert($('#<%=txtTotalVersion.ClientID%>').val());

                       alert($('input[id$=txtTotalVersion]').val());

                      var xTotlal =$('#<%=txtTotalVersion.ClientID%>').val()
                          var i = 0;
                       for (i = 0; i < xTotlal; i++) {

                              $('#createDiv' + i).style.display = "blcok";
                              $('#createDiv1' + i).style.display = "block";
                              $('#createDiv2' + i).style.display = "block";
                              $('#createDiv3' + i).style.display = "block";
                          }

                      });

                  });

              </script>
```

**HTML**

```
   <div id="DivCompName">
         <asp:TextBox runat=server ID="txtTotalVersion" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:TextBox runat=server ID="txtCurrentDisplay" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
      </div>
```

First two alert return undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Visible="false"` is asp.net attribute, in this case your control will not be rendered at the client side. So your client script won't find the control as it doesn't exists!

If you want to store some value at client side and don't want to display it then you can use `HiddenFields` or you can make the same control hidden by using css style `display:none;`. (Don't use `Visible="false"` for this)

Answer (score 0):

you can add ClientIDMode=Static and call it from your jquery

```
<asp:TextBox runat=server ID="txtTotalVersion" Visible="false" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("#txtTotalVersion").val();
    })
</script>
```

reason is, the client id for your control might not be as it is assigned with ID="xxx", if the control is inside of another asp.net server control, after adding the ClientIDMode, you are telling your server to treat this control with a static ID

to learn more: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)